# How to tell shell to re-read the ~/.bashrc?

Tags: command-line, bashrc

How can I tell shell to re-read the `~/.bashrc` without restarting the shell?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Source it again:

```
. ~/.bashrc
# or
source ~/.bashrc
```